# import .dmp in Toad : Invalid format of Import utility name Verify that ORACLE_HOME is properly set

Tags: oracle, database-design, oracle-11g-r2, restore, sqlplus

When I tried to import a DMP file using TOAD (9.0.1) Import Utility Wizard I get an error

> Invalid format of Import utility name  Verify that ORACLE_HOME is
> properly set

Any suggestions please?

I have attached a screen print.

[image]

Comment: The error message looks pretty self-explanatory: "verify that ORACLE_HOME is properly set".  That, in addition to the _earlier_ message "Message 100 not found. No message file for product ..."  is pretty indicative of not having your environment set properly.

Comment: I can’t help but notice that you are running ancient software versions: Toad 9.0.1, Oracle 11.2.0.1 and even your desktop looks like Windows XP. Maybe an upgrade would be in order ?

Comment: The messages in the screen remind me of the NLS_DATA environment variable.

Answer (score 0):

FOR WINDOWS SERVER

Set the ORACLE_HOME environment variable to point to the Oracle Admin Client installation directory.

On Windows:
Right-click My Computer > Properties.
Click Advanced system settings > Environment Variables.
Click New in the System Variables panel.
Add the ORACLE_HOME variable to the New System Variable box, then click OK.
For example: ORACLE_HOME=C:\app\Administrator\product\12.1.0\client_1

Select the PATH variable in the System Variables panel, and click Edit.
In the Edit System Variable box, add the path to ORACLE_HOME at the start of the PATH variable.
%ORACLE_HOME%\bin

By default, the PATH variable already includes the path <ORACLE_HOME>\bin after you install the Oracle client software.

Click OK twice to exit.